# Prior-less estimation of function result

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose we have some real-valued function `f(x)` and several data points for certain values of `x`:

[image]

What would be the best way to estimate the value of `f(x)` for some arbitrary `x` (for example, x = 3.5) without assuming any prior knowledge of `f` internals? Is it possible to derive a probability distribution for `f(x)` for given `x`?

Comment: Which one is best depends on your application. You could do trapezoids, parabolas, Fourier, polynomial, and probably dozens of others, all with their different advantages.

Comment: @Arthur - my understanding is that I would be able to select from those methods if I had some domain-specific knowledge about `f(x)`. But is there some generalized way, that while non-optimal will still converge to real distribution for any function, given enough data points?